# MySQL: detecting a text "NULL" or 0 field and changing it to proper NULL

Tags: mysql, null

I have the following bit of code

```
UPDATE

table_one

SET

field_one = CASE 

   WHEN field_one = 'NULL' OR field_one = 0 
   THEN NULL

   ELSE field_one 

END
```

So I want to see if the field has a string "NULL" or a zero (0) value. if it does then it should be set to a *NULL* within the database.

The issue I'm having is that it's setting everything to *NULL* in some fields while other fields are okay.

Is there anything wrong with the code?

Comment: your case statement is doing an implicit cast of 0 to string.   you say it works on "Some fields"  (columns?) the data type may not be able to cast from one data type to another which would cause a problem for you..

Comment: I guess where I'm lost is " it's setting everything to NULL in some fields"... you're updating a single column here. and it should be setting that row/column to null when it is 0 or 'Null'  so can you give an example where it's not working as expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE table_one
SET    field_one = NULL
WHERE  field_one = 'NULL'
OR     field_one = '0'
```

Comment: This is simplier in that it only updates records that are 'NULL' string or 0; unlike the OP case statement which touches every record.  This should operate faster due to less IO and less error prone.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE table_one SET field_one = NULL WHERE field_one IN ( 0 , 'NULL');
```